# Uncheck all checkboxes across entire workbook via CommandButton

Tags: excel, checkbox, activexobject, vba

I would like to have a code that unchecks all checkboxes named "CheckBox1" for all sheets across the workbook. My current code unfortunately doesn't work, and I'm not sure why - it only works for the active sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Select Case CheckBox1.Value
        Case True: CheckBox1.Value = False
        End Select  
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code iterates through all sheets (*except sheets named `Sheet100` and `OtherSheet`*) and ***unchecks*** all your *`ActiveX`* checkboxes named *`CheckBox1`*

```
Sub uncheck_boxes()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xbox As OLEObject
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet100" And ws.Name <> "OtherSheet" Then
            For Each xbox In ws.OLEObjects
                ws.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = False
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

To uncheck all *`ActiveX`* checkboxes in all sheets disregarding the names used

```
Sub uncheck_all_ActiveX_checkboxes()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xbox As OLEObject
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each xbox In ws.OLEObjects
            ws.OLEObjects(xbox.Name).Object.Value = False
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

To uncheck all *`Form Control checkboxes`* on a spreadsheet use

```
Sub uncheck_forms_checkboxes()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xshape As Shape
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each xshape In ws.Shapes
            If xshape.Type = msoFormControl Then
                xshape.ControlFormat.Value = False
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you mehow for your help. Something quite odd is happening: This appears to work for 2 sheets for which I have created the boxes manually; however, it doesn't appear to work for subsequent sheets, for which I have simply copy pasted the checkboxes and VBA code. I have checked multiple times, and the name of these items are identical to those that I created manually. I really don't see why this wouldn't work? Creating all the boxes manually is not feasible as I have way too many sheets for that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @jcv i see. I bet its something really simple you have somehow overlooked man. open a new workbook and try creating some checkboxes manually and copy some over to other sheets. then run this code and see the behavior. i have tested on my machine and everything works fine. In your case put some `Debug.Print` lines, to see if you are really iterating through all worksheets, all checkboxes etc

Comment: Mehow, thanks man. I have done some analysis and came across a new error - please see my updated main post. When I run your VBA code, I get an error in the CheckBox code @ Case False [...] ActiveSheet.Shapes etc. Can you have a look please?

Answer (score 2):

[edited following comments]

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim s As Object

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Definitions" And ws.Name <> "fx" Then
        Set s = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set s = ws.OLEObjects("CheckBox1")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not s Is Nothing Then
            s.Object.Value = False
        End If
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

This is a global function (it doesn't belong to a particular sheet), but you can put it inside `CommandButton1_Click()` if you want.

You might not need the error blocking if your sheets (other than Definitions and fx) always contain `CheckBox1`. Alternatively remove that if statement.

Comment: Bathsheba, thank you for your quick reply. I tried both of your suggestions and they yield a code error, stating "Expected: expression" and "Object doesn't support this property or method" respectively. They are ActiveX Control elements.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? And, are the check boxes form controls or ActiveX controls (or don't you know)?

Comment: Excel 2007 and ActiveX Controls as stated above

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help! However, there still appears to be a problem... I have updated my main post.