# Set an Option button's value on Excel using Interop on VB

Tags: vb.net, excel, interop

I'm importing a library to modify cells in Excel:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

I'm using this line to modify the value of a cell (oWs being the sheet):

```
oWs.Cells.Range("name").Value = "foo"
```

How would I change an Option Button's value? It seems that I cannot select the button at all.

Comment: my answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818207/excel-vba-uncheck-all-checkboxes-across-entire-workbook-via-commandbutton/16818828#16818828) maye be useful for iterating through OLE objects and shapes

Comment: This is VBA though, I am using VB 2005. Would it work anyway?

Comment: why wouldnt it? VB.NET treats everything as object :) the only difference lies in implementation

Comment: You're absolutely right, it works like a charm! Thank you and if you want to formulate a small answer, I'll give you the checkmark.

Comment: You could upvote the answer in the link instead. im glad it helps