# Show and Hide Shapes in Active Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 2")).Visible = Not ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 2")).Visible
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 3")).Visible = Not ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 3")).Visible
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 4")).Visible = Not ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 4")).Visible
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 5")).Visible = Not ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 5")).Visible
```

This is the sample of code macro that i use

i want to know how we can on run this code to hide only rectangle 1 line

like

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle *")).Visible = _ 
    Not ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle *")).Visible
Next i
```

I just dont know how to simplify correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre not far off , this is how to use the loop to go through all the `Rounded Rectangles`

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle " & i)).Visible = _
    Not ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle " & i)).Visible
Next i
```

note how `"Rounded Rectangle " & i` is replaced with the 
`"Rounded Rectangle 1"` 
`"Rounded Rectangle 2"` 
`"Rounded Rectangle n"` where `n = i` ( meaning the amount of times the loop runs )

---

therefore, if you want to hide only the first one `Rounded Rectangle 1`, then add an ***If/else*** statement to your loop

***note***: this code will never display the first `Rounded Rectangle 1` and **toggle** between showing all the other ones. if you wanted to always show them then just assign **true** inside the else statement

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    If i = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle " & i)).Visible = False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle " & i)).Visible = _
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle " & i)).Visible
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: @eathapeking youre welcome. you can accept the answer clicking the green check mark below the voting counter

Comment: It said it wasnt found the that name :(

Comment: forget dim i as long  :)  but still error

"the item with specific name was not found"

Comment: oh alright, you should always dimension your variables though it's easier NOT to get lost ;) read more about [Option Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: it still show   "the item with specific name was not found"   `:(

Comment: it is exist  when i change it back to use simple "Rounded Rectangle 1" but when change to use for loop "Rounded Rectangle " & i ... it show an error.. i also try using  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array ( i ))   it work to hide all shape

Comment: Check the spelling of the name of `rounded rectangle 1`. make sure it does exist by its name

Comment: ok you may want to use a for each loop instead of an numerical iterator. follow the logic from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818207/excel-vba-uncheck-all-checkboxes-across-entire-workbook-via-commandbutton/16818828#16818828)