# How to delete only 1 checkbox from any particular cell?

Tags: excel, vba

How to delete only 1 checkbox from any particular cell(say in "C38") using Excel VBA?

Comment: is it associated with the cell ? do you know the name of that checkbox? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818207/excel-vba-uncheck-all-checkboxes-across-entire-workbook-via-commandbutton/16818828#16818828) is a good starting point

Comment: Yes it is associated with the same cell (C38)

Comment: Also, please note that the checkbox is unnamed

Comment: I have got the code to delete multiple checkboxes, but just cant seem to delete 1 particular checkbox  

‘Code to Delete all checkboxes in a sheet
For Each vShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
vShape.Delete
Next vShape

Comment: it cannot be unnamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little guide to **<kbd>how to delete a specific shape</kbd>**

[image: shape name]

As you can see, selecting a shape will show you its name in the *`Name box` (placed on the left side of the formula box)*. In the above example, the name of the selected shape is **`Rectangle 1`**
If you want to delete a specific shape you have to know its name *(well, if unless it's a specific shape that has its own properties different than any other shape but I will not cover this in here)*
The easiest way to get the name of the shape you want to delete it's to click on the shape and look for the name in the *`Name box`*.

Once you know the name you can modify your current code and add an [if statement](http://www.ozgrid.com/News/ExcelLogicalFunctionsIfAndOrVBARangeNames.htm) to get a match on one item from `Shapes` collection.

```
Sub DeleteShape()
    Dim vShape
    For Each vShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If StrComp(CStr(vShape), CStr("Rectangle 1"), 1) = 0 Then
            vShape.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much mehow :) This explanation helped me a great deal!! Its working now :D :D I m so happy!! Thanks!!

Comment: youre welcome. Here on stackoverflow we say thank you by accepting the answer ( green check mark next to the answer )