# Use For Loop to obtain values from multiple textboxes in Excel VBA

Tags: string, excel, vba, for-loop

For a VBA code in Excel (not a userform) I have 4 textboxes named `TextBox1` to `TextBox4`.

I want to obtain the values from these textboxes using a for loop. The goal is to search for a value in a corresponding column (`D` in this case). Therefore I search in the selected sheet (named after the selected value in the `UpdateComboBox`). To be able to search I first select the rownumber corresponding to the Weld showed in `RelatedWeldTextBox_i`. This value differs following other input boxes.

The code below is wrong. It creates a String with the for loop: `TextBox1` for example. But it starts searching column `D` for the String `TextBox1` instead of the value presented in this textbox. If I use `Weld = Textbox1.Value` The code works but only for `Textbox1` of course...

```
Sub RelatedWeldNegative ()

Dim Weld As String
Dim Bmin As Integer
Dim Bmax As Integer 
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 4`

Weld = "Textbox" & i & ".Value"
        For Each Cell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(UpdateComboBox.Value).Range("C2:C320")
           If Cell.Text = Weld Then
            SelecRow = Cell.Row
            End If
Next

Next i
Bmax = 6
Bmin = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(UpdateComboBox.Value).Cell(SelecRow, "D")
'follow up with code
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,

Miriam

Comment: What *kind* of textbox?  There's more than one kind and they are accessed somewhat differently from VBA.  Can you describe precisely how they were created?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncheck all checkboxes across entire workbook via CommandButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818207/uncheck-all-checkboxes-across-entire-workbook-via-commandbutton). Please look [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818207/uncheck-all-checkboxes-across-entire-workbook-via-commandbutton/16818828#16818828) as it demonstrates how to iterate over Form and ActiveX controls

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to loop over TextBoxes:

```
Sub dural()
    For i = 1 To 4
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox " & i).Select
        MsgBox Selection.Characters.Text
    Next i
End Sub
```

Another Way

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 4
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox" & i)

        Debug.Print shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 I think you have an Extra space in `"TextBox "` and also you don't need to select it :)

Comment: I put the Extra space in because on my system **Insert** automatically names them with the extra space................it is nice to see a way to get the text without the **Select** ..........thanks!

Comment: Ah ok. On my sheet it doesn't insert that space :)